# sending data and receiving data from mysql database in the same webpage

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a discussion board as my own project, right now I have a page where a user enter his comment, and another page where it confirms that his comment was posted, and then a third page where you could see all the comments. All this is done using php and mysql as the database that holds all the users information such as the users, name, comments, date ,etc.

What I am trying to do is instead of having three pages, I just want one page where the user enters his comment and he can see the comments right away in the same page. Can this be done, are there any good tutorials i can look at online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using [Ajax](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax).